# C# WPF DataGrid Binding with ObservableCollection doesnt work

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have this `ObservableCollection`

```
public static ObservableCollection<NahrungsmittelKategorie> NahrungsmittelKategorie
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

this `nahrungsmittelkategorie.cs`

```
public class NahrungsmittelKategorie
{
    public int NahrungsmittelID { get; set; }
    public string NahrungsmittelName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Kategorie> NahrungsmittelKategorien { get; set; }
}
```

this method:

```
ObservableCollection<NahrungsmittelKategorie> ListNahrungsmittel = new ObservableCollection<NahrungsmittelKategorie>();
        MySqlConnection connection = SQLConnection.getConnection();
        MySqlCommand cmdGetNahrungsmittel = new MySqlCommand("Select ID, Name from t_Nahrungsmittel", connection);
        connection.Open();
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmdGetNahrungsmittel.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            NahrungsmittelKategorie n = new NahrungsmittelKategorie();
            n.NahrungsmittelID = reader.GetInt32(0);
            n.NahrungsmittelName = reader.GetString(1);
            ListNahrungsmittel.Add(n);
        }
        connection.Close();

        for (int i = 0; i < ListNahrungsmittel.Count; i++)
        {
            ObservableCollection<Kategorie> ListKategorie = new ObservableCollection<Kategorie>();
            MySqlCommand cmdGetKategorien = new MySqlCommand("Select t_kategorie.id, t_kategorie.Kategorie from t_kategorie " +
                "inner join t_nahrungsmittelkategorie on t_kategorie.id = t_nahrungsmittelkategorie.kategorie " +
                "inner join t_nahrungsmittel on t_nahrungsmittelkategorie.nahrungsmittel = t_nahrungsmittel.id " +
                "where t_nahrungsmittel.id = " + ListNahrungsmittel[i].NahrungsmittelID, connection);
            connection.Open();
            reader = cmdGetKategorien.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Kategorie k = new Kategorie();
                k.KategorieID = reader.GetInt32(0);
                k.KategorieKategorie = reader.GetString(1);
                ListKategorie.Add(k);
            }
            connection.Close();
            ListNahrungsmittel[i].NahrungsmittelKategorien = ListKategorie;
        }

        NahrungsmittelKategorie = ListNahrungsmittel;
    }
```

and at last this xaml code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataNahrungsmittel" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=NahrungsmittelKategorie}" ColumnWidth="1*" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding NahrungsmittelID}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nahrungsmittel" Binding="{Binding NahrungsmittelName}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I dont get the values in the DataGrid. Can someone tell me whats wrong? I have tested a lot of solutions.

These is the DataGrid after that:

[image]

if i get this code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataNahrungsmittel" ItemsSource="{Binding NahrungsmittelKategorie}" ColumnWidth="1*" AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False">
```

I get this datagrid:

[image]

Comment: Are there any binding error in output when you open the window/page/control where the DataGrid is?

Comment: I only get an empty datagrid with much empty rows. show the pictures in question

Comment: Are you setting DataContext correctly?

Comment: What does u mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you populating a list and then assigning that to the list that is bound to the datagrid, then you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for that.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataNahrungsmittel" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=NahrungsmittelKategorie}"></DataGrid>
```

When you do the above binding, at that time the `NahrungsmittelKategorie` is empty.

and at the following line, the `NahrungsmittelKategorie` is updated but it does not notify the datagrid that the bound collection is changed.

```
NahrungsmittelKategorie = ListNahrungsmittel;
```

You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and notify the property at the time of assignment (which is in setter)

```
private static ObservableCollection<NahrungsmittelKategorie> nahrungsmittelKategorie = new ObservableCollection<NahrungsmittelKategorie>();

public static ObservableCollection<NahrungsmittelKategorie> NahrungsmittelKategorie
{
    get { return nahrungsmittelKategorie; }
    set { nahrungsmittelKategorie = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("NahrungsmittelKategorie")};
}
```

where `NotifyPropertyChanged` will be the method you will write when you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Your idea has get me to the right idea. I created a refresh method where i bind the itemssoource new. Thanks

Comment: That does the job but its very bad performance wise. Setting ItemsSource null and then resetting to a collection force datagrid to recreate whole bindings. notifying means just getting the latest changes. If you read on MSDN about their differences, you can observe the time duration both cases take.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your view's DataContext?

Your Xaml should look like :

```
<YourRootElement x:Name="yourName">
...
</YourRootElement>
```

And your Xaml.Cs constructor sould look like this :

```
public YourClassName()
{
  InitialiseComponent();
  yourName.dataContext = this;
}
```

Comment: He is binding static collection to datagrid. I think setting DataContext = this will not have any effect because static variables are object level, instead those are class level and doesn't have a this.